# Possivel falha de seguraça utilizando Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou ajudando a fazer um sistema de prospecções. E acabo me deparando com um incidente que fiquei um pouco em duvida se seria algo comum ou algo que poderia tornar-se uma vulnerabiliade futuramente.

Estou utilizando Laravel. Estou atualmente mexendo com gráficos e quero analisar dados do inicio do mês com o mês atual.

```
$date_start = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$date_end = Carbon::now();

$prospectMonth = Prospect::whereBetween('created_at',[$date_start,$date_end]);
```

Porém fui analisar a procedencia desses dados com o comando `dd()` e na tela aparece os seguintes dados.

```
dd($prospectMonth);



Builder {#352 ▼
  #query: Builder {#351 ▼
    +connection: MySqlConnection {#334 ▼
      #pdo: PDOConnection {#343 ▶}
      #readPdo: null
      #database: "----"
      #tablePrefix: ""
      #config: array:15 [▶]
      #reconnector: Closure($connection) {#337 ▶}
      #queryGrammar: MySqlGrammar {#335 ▶}
      #schemaGrammar: null
      #postProcessor: MySqlProcessor {#336}
      #events: Dispatcher {#26 ▶}
      #fetchMode: 5
      #transactions: 0
      #recordsModified: false
      #queryLog: []
      #loggingQueries: false
      #pretending: false
      #doctrineConnection: null
    }
    +grammar: MySqlGrammar {#335 ▶}
    +processor: MySqlProcessor {#336}
    +bindings: array:7 [▶]
    +aggregate: null
    +columns: null
    +distinct: false
    +from: "prospect"
    +joins: null
    +wheres: array:1 [▶]
    +groups: null
    +havings: null
    +orders: null
    +limit: null
    +offset: null
    +unions: null
    +unionLimit: null
    +unionOffset: null
    +unionOrders: null
    +lock: null
    +operators: array:29 [▶]
    +useWritePdo: false
  }
  #model: Prospect {#350 ▼
    +fillable: array:15 [▶]
    #table: "prospect"
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:13 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

Nunca chegou de aparecer esse `Builder` utilizando o laravel para qualquer analise que fiz. A minha duvida é, se estou fazendo algo errado na maneira de chamar os dados do inicio do mes até o dia atual do mês, ou se é um problema de segurança ou do Laravel ou do Carbon.

*Obs: Em config dentro da query do Builder aparece as configurações do meu banco de dados.*

Comment: Só será um problema de segurança se você utilizar a ferramenta de forma errada; a função `dd` foi criada para facilitar o processo no ambiente de desenvolvimento e, idealmente, jamais deveria ir para o ambiente de produção. Então aparecer os dados de conexão do banco não é um problema, visto que só a equipe de desenvolvimento verá esse retorno.

Comment: Como no fim da query você não esta usando um `>get()` para obter os dados o `dd` mostra informação de sua conexão / **Builder** .

Answer (score 1):

Usando query builder:

```
$date_start = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$date_end = Carbon::now();

$prospectMonth = Prospect::whereBetween('created_at',[$date_start,$date_end])->get();
```

Caso queira a soma após `get()` coloca `->sum()`, caso queira só um coloca `first()` no lugar do `get()`